# Low-level word problem: calculate a split based on difference

Tags: algebra-precalculus

My roommate and I have different amounts of take-home income. We are splitting a set of expenses. Besides trial and error, how can I calculate the correct split if the goal is that we each have the same amount of cash after paying off the expenses?

```
A = my take-home
B = roommate's  take-home
X = monthly expenses
p = percentage of X I pay
1 - p =  percentage of X roommate pays
```

The best I can come up with is

> $A - pX = B - ((1 - p)X)$

Sadly, I end up with $A/X - B/X = 1/p$, which is probably wrong as well as definitely being non-useful.

$A$, $B$, and $X$ are real values, so a result expressed in those terms is fine.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you say is that you want each to have the same amount left after paying expenses.  If that is the goal, the amount left is $A+B-X$ and you should each have half that left.  So you should pay $A-\frac 12(A+B-X)=\frac 12(A+X-B)$ and your roommate should pay $\frac 12(B+X-A)$

If instead you think you should pay a fraction proportional to your pay, the fraction is $\frac X{A+B}$, so you should pay $\frac {AX}{A+B}$ and he should pay $\frac {BX}{A+B}$.  These are two different allocations.

Comment: @Richard Just be warned that if you earn much more than your roommate, you'd end up giving him money.